# How to properly start gvfs without gnome?

Tags: linux, fuse

I have a Debian testing box with Xfce (no Gnome, *no* Nautilus). It has all gvfs-related stuff installed, including all backends and fuse interface. But any attempts to `gvfs-mount` anything (like sftp://... or smb://...) fail with `error opening file: Operation not supported`, and `gigolo` shows only 'unix device (file)' in the list of supported protocols.

My `~/.gvfs` has `rwx` permissions, and I'm a member of `fuse` group; other fuse-related stuff works for me.

What do I do? Where to look?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is based on the behavior I've seen in Arch Linux. Hopefully it is not much different from Debian's. (Also, because it was empirically determined, I am not sure if it is going to be actually a good one.)

It seems like you have to ensure that gvfsd and gvfs-fuse-daemon are running. Unfortunately, in my case starting them manually didn't have the desired effect. They started, but the problems persisted.

Since gvfs exports dbus services, it seems like gvfsd should be actually started by dbus. Are you using a display manager to log in or are you calling startx directly?

If you are calling startx (or using a display manager like SLiM), try to invoke your window manager/desktop environment with

```
exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session --sh-syntax startxfce4
```

in your `$HOME/.xinitrc`.

If you are using a display manager, check in its documentation what to do to customize how the window manager is called.

Comment: Somehow it started to work after I've switched to GDM (instead of startx). Thank you nevertheless; I'll try this with startx sometime.

Comment: No problem. Regarding the fact that it suddenly worked with gdm, that's because gdm is probably calling dbus-launch for you. Check http://ln-s.net/8rwu if interested.

Comment: Someone with this problem using LightDM? XFCE works pretty fine here, but AwesomeWM don't. It's a quite weird.

Comment: Current Xfce knows how to start dbus, and has a GUI control for it, so this answer is already superfluous. AwesomeWM probably does not do this.